# Docker Desktop can't get container logs

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop, docker-logs

I'm using Docker Desktop on Win10. Containers works correctly and when I start container without -d parameter I see logs in cosnole output. Also when I use command *docker logs* I can see the logs. Unluckily when I try to get logs from Docker Desktop Logs tab I see:
`No such container: fb1c4bd5bc56031edb44e0c2e1e4ebd5c281f1a2d96bbc2b16249154e0c2d013`

I tryed reinstall Docker Desktop but it doesn't help. This problem appeard a couple month ago    , actually I have the newest (4.12.0) version.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: According to the github issues they had a fix after the docker desktop vetsion 3.4.however i do not sure it is exact same issue.

Comment: You are using wsl1 or wsl2?

Comment: I am using WSL2

Comment: You are using a distro ot not?

Comment: I'm using distro Ubuntu but this problem also appears on Windows containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting all execting containers and volumes with :

```
docker system prune
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

After that, [reset your wsl distro](https://superuser.com/questions/1446409/how-can-i-reset-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-back-to-defaults).

Comment: It Didn't help, Still can't get logs in Docker Desktop

Comment: Ok, little update. It works! but after doing that I had problems with building images so i again reinstall docker. After Reinstal everything works!

Comment: Glad to hear it